# Conditional expectation $E((X+Y)^2|X)$ and $E((X+Y)^2|XY)$ given $X, Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

It's the first time I'm working with conditional expectation, so I need to ensure my reasoning is correct:

> Let $\Omega = [0, \pi]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and probability equal to normalized Lebesgue measure. Let $X(\omega) = \sin{\omega}, Y(\omega) = \cos{\omega}$. Calculate $E((X+Y)^2|X)$ and $E((X+Y)^2|XY)$.

First of all, since X and Y are trigonometric functions, $X^2 + Y^2 = 1$, which leads to $(X+Y)^2 = 2XY + 1$. Therefore:

$E((X+Y)^2|X) = E(2XY+1|X) = 2 E(XY|X) + E(1|X)$, because conditional expected value is linear. Now:

$E(1|X)=1$, since the function is constant.

$E(XY|X) = Y E(X|X) = XY$, because $Y$ is $X$-measurable and bounded.

Thus the final result is  $E((X+Y)^2|X) = 2XY +1$. I've got the same result in the second conditional expectation due to similar reasoning.

How wrong am I? 
Should I extend this answer by calculating $\int \limits_{A} (2XY +1)dP$ for some Borel $A$ from this $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How wrong am I?

Just a little bit.

Now $\mathsf E((X+Y)^2\mid XY) ~=~ 1+2XY$ is okay.

However, $\mathsf E((X+Y)^2\mid X) ~$$=~ 1$ because $\mathsf E(XY\mid X) = 0$

Since $\mathsf E(XY\mid X) ~=~ \mathsf E(X\cos(\arcsin X)\mid X) ~=~0$

(For each value of $X$ there exists two equally possible values of $Y$, one positive and one negative.)

Comment: (+1) to be explicit: $E(XY|X) = X E (Y|X) = 0$, because $E(Y|X)=0$, as per your edit.

Comment: No @πr8 .  What values can $\cos(\omega)$ have if $\sin(\omega) = \sqrt{1/2}$ , where $\omega\in[0;\pi]$ ?

Comment: @peterag how do I calculate $E(Y|X)$? I don't really understand this explanation

Comment: @Angie - if you draw a picture, I think you'll see:  if $X$ is in a small interval, where is $Y$, and what will its expectation be? This is Graham's comment to $\pi r8$, I think.

Comment: Since $X\in[0;1]$ certainly, then taking $\arcsin()$ as the first quadrant angle, we have $\mathsf E (Y \mid X) = \tfrac 12\big( \cos(\arcsin(X)) + \cos(\pi-\arcsin(X))\big) = 0$

Comment: my mistake - was confused by the (odd) choice of having $x=\sin, y=\cos$

Comment: @Angie to be clearer: say $I$ is a small interval in $(0,1)$, then $X^{-1} ( I )$ consists of  2 disjoint intervals $J_{-}$ and $J_{+}$, and the integrals of $Y$ on each of the $J$ cancel each other.

Comment: @peterag oh, now I see this, thanks!

Comment: @GrahamKemp - I hope your ok with my add-on to your explanation...